# How to make a modal responsive in bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a modal that opens at the bottom of the page responsively.

In this example, the modal it appears from bottom to top. I want him to arise under and stay there.

In this example, changing the position, managed to get the modal appear in the footer, but it is not responsive, it does not fit the content. When I insert great content, it appears only half and the rest of the content is unable to see.

I want it that way:

[image: Example]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vaiandrept4/gamge71q/1/

Comment: the code is up there guy! Open the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.modal-dialog{
  position:absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom:0;
  margin-left: -250px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/gamge71q/4/)**

Comment: Thank so much! It's worked!